# Storing in IndexedDB using Pinia

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, indexeddb, pinia

Is it possible to store data locally in IndexedDB using Pinia ?

I tried using Pinia persisted state and it stores data locally in LocalStorage as default. I just want to try if it will work with IndexedDB since it has a larger size capacity.

Answer (score 9):

You can implement your own pinia plugin to use whatever storage you want.
Here is an example using [localForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage).

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia, type Store } from 'pinia'
import App from './App.vue'
import localForage from "localforage";

const app = createApp(App)

// Optional
localForage.config({
    driver: localForage.INDEXEDDB, // This force IndexedDB as the driver
})

async function indexDbPlugin({ store }: { store: Store }) {
    const stored = await localForage.getItem(store.$id + '-state')
    if (stored) {
        store.$patch(stored)
    }
    store.$subscribe(() => {
        localForage
            .setItem(store.$id + '-state', { ...store.$state }) // Destructure to transform to plain object
    })
}

const pinia = createPinia()
pinia.use(indexDbPlugin)

app.use(pinia)
app.mount('#app')
```

https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/plugins.html#introduction

But with the plugin `pinia-plugin-persistedstate` you cannot use indexDb as it is asynchronous and this plugin only supports synchronous storage:

https://prazdevs.github.io/pinia-plugin-persistedstate/guide/limitations.html#storage-must-be-synchronous

Comment: I see. Is there any chance to use Pinia State Management with IndexedDB?

Comment: You could implement your own plugin, updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

This plugin allowed to persists the store with the indexedDB but it is no longer maintained:

https://github.com/iendeavor/pinia-plugin-persistedstate-2

## EDIT

This plugin is no longer maintained.